# Nearly Fresh Install of Kubuntu 19.10 Deadlocks Upon Entering Wi-Fi Password?

Tags: encryption, kubuntu

I have a nearly fresh install of Kubuntu 19.10 with an encrypted home folder.

The home folder was encrypted using `ecryptfs-migrate-home` as usual and the [appropriate steps were taken](https://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/).

However, I've developed several bugs as a result of this. The most prominant (And threatening) is a bug involving entering my wi-fi password into the password box in the system tray.

When I do so, the system deadlocks immediatly. Even entering Ctrl + F2 or Alt + F2 doesn't work, and the state stays like this indefinitely.

I'm not sure what package to file a bug report on using `ubuntu-bug` either.

How should I approach this problem?

**EDIT 0:** Hardware Specs:

```
sarah@LesserArk:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev bb)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Can you define "the approtiate steps" ? have you dismounted the folder, have you used it before... Install and use encryptfs utilities > https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-and-use-ecryptfs-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @vssher Sorry, I followed this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/